# An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.palantir.configuration-resolver', version: '0.1.0']

Tags: android, gradle

I have cloned  the following repository for muun wallet:
https://github.com/muun/apollo
I am receiving the following error during Gradle build.

```
**Error:**

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.palantir.configuration-resolver', version: '0.1.0']
Failed to apply plugin 'com.palantir.configuration-resolver'.
Could not create task ':android:apolloui:resolveConfigurations'.
Cannot create task ':android:apolloui:resolveConfigurations' of type 'ResolveConfigurationsTask' 
as directly extending AbstractTask is not supported
```

I am using Windows 7 (64 bit), and JDK embedded in Android Studio. I have not made any changes to the code. Any suggestions on how to resolve the issue?

Thanks in Advance!